# Centre two divs on dreamweaver fluid grid layout

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I've been trying to get two div's to be centered sat next to each other using dreamweaver fluid grid system. I've tried many different things to get them centered. I've got close,playing with the margin but as i pull on the window to resize the browser window, the percentage I've set doesn't quite workout, making the div's either too much to the left or right or throwing the div on the right on to a new line between desktop and tablet screen sizes. i think the issue is the div on the left which has a fixed pixel width and some empty grid line space on the design layout in dreamweaver. I cant find any answers online to this..... please can someone help. and it looks like I've got to search for how to put code on here correct too. sorry about this.... first time on here.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonvarley2014/JsE7L/)

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
 <div class="fluid header">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "header"</div>
<div class="fluid vid">
   <iframe width="100%" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RZyPHa3gxE0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="fluid img hide_mobile"><img src="Screen shot 2014-05-21 at 12.15.22.png"  alt=""/></div>
<div class="fluid button zeroMargin_desktop">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "button"</div>
<div class="fluid vid">
   <iframe width="100%" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RZyPHa3gxE0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="fluid img hide_mobile"><img src="Screen shot 2014-05-21 at 12.15.22.png"  alt=""/></div>
<div class="fluid button zeroMargin_desktop">This is the content for Layout Div Tag "button"</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera/IE 8+ */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
The box-sizing CSS property is used to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate widths and heights of elements.

**border-box** - The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin.

So, instead of margin

```
.img {
margin-left: 2.5641%;
}
```

make it with padding

```
.img {
padding-left: 2.5641%;
}
```

and your layout should be fine.

Comment: Please add some more information to your post, for example explain what `box-sizing` does.